# Is it mandatory for .NET to have the root CA certificate available before using a pfx certificate as client certificate for a secure SOAP request?

Tags: .net, web-services, ssl

I am writing a .NET application that has to use an API of Webservices made available by an outside provider. This provider gave me a pfx certificate (and a password) that I must use to authenticate my HTTP client to their servers.

When I use SOAPUI to access the Web Service with this certificate and this password, the Web Service answers fine.

When I try to create a .NET client as a  Web Reference, the connection fails, telling me that "Authentication failed, the peer having closed the connection".

Drilling down with Wireshark and comparing datastreams, I witness that SOAPUI sends the client certificate in response to the server certificate, whereas the .NET program does not. The client certificate is loaded into the ClientsCertificate collection, but .NET refuses to send the client certificate.

The certificate is issued and signed by a CA held by the outside provider, but we don't have the CA certificate.

My current theory is that .NET refuses to use the certificate if it can't validate the cert chain. Is it the case, and in which case, is there a way to bypass this verification?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to do SFTP in a vb.net application, I added this code to the top of the page.

```
Public Sub New()
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf CertificateAuthenticate)
End Sub
Private Function CertificateAuthenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

So in a normal FTP client, the ftp client would prompt the user to "trust" the certificate, so this "return True" essentially tells the .net application to trust the certificate.  Not sure if this is the answer, but hope it is helpful.

Comment: No, actually, it seems that it's not that the server certificate is untrusted, but the application does not send the client certificate in response to the reception of the server certificate, and follows up with an encrypted stream instead, causing the server to close the connection.